# Parallel datareaders on the same topic

Tags: data-distribution-service

I have a question that I'm curious about, but can't find the answer to exactly. Suppose we have a datawriter and a datareader and as a topic, we have an airplane's flight runtime information such as coordinates, etc. And suppose that datareader should take a heavy process from this information. When there is more than 100 flight at the same time, parallel operation of multiple datareaders seems to be a suitable solution. But I think multiplexing Datareaders won't make sense since because they will all process the same message (topic) in parallel in the same way. Alternative solution. To make the DataReader multithread. But this time there will be only one datareader. And we will have a constraint.

What kind of approach can be created in dds to create multiple datareaders and process them in parallel to distribute the workload.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSpliceDDS implements an extension to the DDS specification to do exactly this i.e. using its *DDS_ShareQoSPolicy* on a subscriber/reader that allows sharing of entities by multiple processes or threads. When that policy is enabled, OpenSplice will try to lookup an existing entity that matches the name supplied in that *ShareQoSPolicy*. A new entity will only be created if a shared entity registered under the specified name doesn't exist yet.
Shared Readers can be useful for implementing algorithms like the worker pattern,
where a single shared reader can contain samples representing different tasks that
may be processed in parallel by separate processes. In this algorithm each process
consumes the (samples related to the) task it is going to perform (i.e. it *takes* the samples representing that task) thus preventing other processes from consuming and therefore performing *the same* task.

**NOTE**: Entities can only be shared between co-located processes where OpenSplice is running in federated mode where shared memory is exploited to share the data between the readers of the set of federated processes (so this doesn't work over machine-boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

In Connext DDS, one can efficiently configure multiple DataReaders to subscribe to a specific Key - one or more fields comprises a @key in the IDL.
So you could modulo-by-5 the flight number field and let 5